# Gradle Spring Boot Test always showing closing context messages

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, gradle

When building a **Spring Boot** application using **Gradle 4.x**, after all tests have run, the console shows a log message for each Spring context being closed that was created by the test:

```
:clean
:compileJava
:processResources NO-SOURCE
:classes
:jar
:assemble
:compileTestJava
:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
:testClasses
:test
INFO 21140 --- [       Thread-5] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Closing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@14c8305c: startup date [Fri Mar 23 16:54:13 CET 2018]; root of context hierarchy
:check
:build
```

IMO, only warnings and errors should be displayed. I created a minimal application to reproduce the issue:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ContextTest {
    @Test public void contextShouldBeCreated() {}
}
```

Here's the `build.gradle`:

```
plugins { id 'java' }

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories { mavenCentral() }

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.5.10.RELEASE"
    testCompile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:1.5.10.RELEASE"
}
```

As a workaround, I set the log level for these classes to `WARN` in `logback-test.xml`:

```
<logger name="org.springframework.context" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="org.springframework.web.context" level="WARN"/>
```

But a real solution would be great. I tried with various versions from 4.0 to 4.6, all producing the same result.

Comment: Tested with 1.5.12.RELEASE - no change

Comment: Experiencing the same thing here. I think it has to do with the fact that the :test task has actually completed when this messages are logged.